# rebuilding listview.builder every time I scroll , and 'Stream has already been listened to' error

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using a stream builder which has another stream builder inside it. Every time I get data from the first stream I use some of this data in the other stream to finally build a list view (POSTS), but I have a problem every time I scroll down I have this error:

```
if (!_isInitialState) {
  throw StateError("Stream has already been listened to.");
}
```

I tried to listen to the second stream asBroadcastStream(), and I added the case that there is no data and every time I scroll I get the notification I made that there is no data any ideas?

This is my code:

```
StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
stream: posts.snapshots(),
builder: (context, snapshot) {
  if (snapshot.hasError) {
    return const Text('Something went wrong');
  }

  if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
    return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
  }
  return SizedBox(
    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.69,
    child: ListView(
      scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
      children:
          snapshot.data!.docs.map((DocumentSnapshot document) {
        Map<String, dynamic> data =
            document.data()! as Map<String, dynamic>;

        return StreamBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
            stream: users
                .doc(data['Uid'])
                .get()
                .asStream()
                .asBroadcastStream(),
            builder: (BuildContext context,
                AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot> snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasError) {
                return const Text("Something went wrong");
              }

              if (snapshot.hasData && !snapshot.data!.exists) {}
              if (!(snapshot.hasData)) {
                print("no data");
                return SizedBox(
                  width: 0,
                );
              }
              if (snapshot.connectionState ==
                  ConnectionState.done) {
                Map<String, dynamic> daata = snapshot.data!
                    .data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
                String username = daata['Username'];
                String userimage = daata['Userimage'];

                return mypost(
                    context,
                    data['title'],
                    data['ImageUrl'],
                    data['context'],
                    username,
                    userimage,
                    data['nlikes'],
                    data['ncomments'],
                    data['date']
                        .toDate()
                        .toString()
                        .split(' ')
                        .first);
              }
              return const Text("loading");
            });
      }).toList(),
    ),
  );
}),
```

if any could help I would be happy with that.

Comment: Ok, for one thing, it looks like you are returning a StreamBuilder() as the only child to a ListView()... Why use a ListView(), if it's only gonna have one child?

Comment: i use listview for the scrolling and it's actually returning many elements .. so it go to the documents and map to ech one . and every time it's returning a data this data i use it to build a post .. so with many data i get many post . and if you didn't notice there .tolist() in the end of the build method .. so this is it . i wish i made it clear

Comment: Yes, I saw that after I've put the code in my IDE and tried figuring out what's going on...  But you know what, I'm pretty good at reading raw code... but I'm seriously struggling with yours!  You should make it more human-friendly... Try and put long expressions in short variable names, and then use the variable in your tree, etc...

Comment: Btw, what does your screen look like, after you've run this code? Are there two scrolling widgets (like a list of lists, where both lists scroll) or just one...? And plz post your whole code! Including this `mypost()`...

Answer (score 0):

It might interest you to know that when I run the below code (basically your code, but with my streams and `mypost()` function) I don't get any errors!... It scrolls fine!

```
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:my_app/firebase_labels.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Screen(),
    );
  }
}

class MyFirebase {
  static FirebaseFirestore storeObject = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
}

class Screen extends StatelessWidget {
  Screen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  // Let me just define some streams here, from the same CollectionReference:
  final CollectionReference posts = MyFirebase.storeObject
      .collection(kCollectionConversations);
  final CollectionReference users = MyFirebase.storeObject
      .collection(kCollectionConversations);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body:   StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
          stream: posts.snapshots(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasError) {
              return const Text('Something went wrong');
            }

            if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
              return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
            }
            return SizedBox(
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.69,
              child: ListView(
                scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                children:
                snapshot.data!.docs.map((DocumentSnapshot document) {
                  Map<String, dynamic> data =
                  document.data()! as Map<String, dynamic>;

                  return StreamBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
                      stream: users
                          .doc(data['Uid'])
                          .get()
                          .asStream()
                          .asBroadcastStream(),
                      builder: (BuildContext context,
                          AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot> snapshot) {
                        if (snapshot.hasError) {
                          return const Text("Something went wrong");
                        }

                        if (snapshot.hasData && !snapshot.data!.exists) {}
                        if (!(snapshot.hasData)) {
                          print("no data");
                          return SizedBox(
                            width: 0,
                          );
                        }
                        if (snapshot.connectionState ==
                            ConnectionState.done) {
                          Map<String, dynamic>? daata = snapshot.data!
                              .data() as Map<String, dynamic>?;
                          String username = '';
                          String userimage = '';
                          if (daata != null) {
                            username = daata['Username'];
                            userimage = daata['Userimage'];
                          }

                          return mypost(
                              data,
                              // context,
                              data['title'],
                              data['ImageUrl'],
                              data['context'],
                              username,
                              userimage,
                              data['nlikes'],
                              data['ncomments'],
                              // data['date']
                              //     .toDate()
                              //     .toString()
                              //     .split(' ')
                              //     .first
                          );
                        }
                        return const Text("loading");
                      });
                }
                ).toList(),
              ),
            );
          }),
    );
  }
}

Widget mypost(var data1, var data2, var data3, var data4, var data5, var data6, var data7, var data8/*, var data9,*/) {
  return Container(
    // height: 50,
    child: Text('$data1'),
    decoration: BoxDecoration(border: Border.all(color: Colors.blue)),
  );
}
```

If you copy-paste this code into yours, do you get errors?

What if you change the streams for yours and the `mypost()` for yours? Do you get errors then?